# jQuery PHP MySQL Like button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to create a like button using PHP, MySQL and jQuery, but seems there's an error, i don't know where is it, can you help ?

I have two pages [index.php & callback.php]

INDEX

```
$k = 1; //POST ID

$nip = 24; //USER ID

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.like', function(){
            if($(this).attr('title')=='Like'){
                $.post('callback.php',{k:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'},function(){
                    $(this).text('Unlike');
                    $(this).attr('title','Unlike');
                });
            }else{
                if($(this).attr('title')=='Unlike'){
                    $.post('callback.php',{k:$(this).attr('id'),action:'unlike'},function(){
                        $(this).text('Like');
                        $(this).attr('title','Like');
                    });
                 }
             }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE nip = :nip AND value = :value");
$query->execute(array(
    ':nip'      => $meNip,
    ':value'    => $k
    )
);
$all = $query->rowCount();
if($query->rowCount()==1){
    echo '<a href="#" class="like" id="'.$k.'" title="Unlike">Unlike</a> <b>'.$all.'</b>';
}else{
    echo '<a href="#" class="like" id="'.$k.'" title="Like">Like</a> <b>'.$all.'</b>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

CALLBACK

```
$nip= //COOKIE

$k= $_POST['k'];

$action=$_POST['action'];

if (!empty($k)) {
    $checkAd=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ad WHERE id = :id");
    $checkAd->execute(array(
        ':id'   => $k
        )
    );
    $checkingAd=$checkAd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($checkingAd as $row) {

    //LIKE
    if ($action=='like'){
        $callback=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE nip = :nip AND value = :value");
        $callback->execute(array(
            ':nip' => $meNip,
            ':value' => $k
            )
        );
        $matches=$callback->rowCount();
        if($matches==0){
        $callback=$db->prepare("UPDATE ad SET likes = :likes WHERE id = :id");
        $callback->execute(array(
            ':likes'    => $row['likes']+1,
            ':id'   => $k
            )
        );
        $callback=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO activity (nip, value) VALUES(:nip, :value)");
        $callback->execute(array(
            ':nip'  => $meNip,
            ':value' => $k
            )
        );
    }
    }elseif ($action=='unlike'){ //UNLIKE
        $callback=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE nip = :nip AND value = :value");
        $callback->execute(array(
            ':nip'  => $meNip,
            ':value' => $k
            )
        );

        $matches=$callback->rowCount();
        if($matches==1){
            $callback=$db->prepare("UPDATE ad SET likes = :likes WHERE id = :id");
            $callback->execute(array(
                ':likes' => $row['likes']-1,
                ':id'   => $k
                )
            );
            $callback=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM activity  WHERE nip = :nip AND value = :value");
            $callback->execute(array(
                ':nip'  => $meNip,
                ':value' => $k
                )
            );
            }
        }
    }
 }
 ?>
```

I tested the callback.php file, (address bar using GET) it's working fine, can you check the INDEX, i think, i miss something, a dot ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: what is the issue you're facing? Like/Unlike aren't being registered in the DB? Are you sure this if is working: if($(this).attr('title')=='Like'){? And did you check your browser's console to see what data is being sent to callback.php

Comment: @tftd Like/Unlike don't work, nothing's posting to callback.php file

Comment: is there a post at all?

Comment: you cant create a button using php and mysql. have to use frontend lang :D

Comment: Why someone gave him/her a down-vote for this question? Whats wrong about it?

Comment: I deleted the history, now when i click on like, is being registered in DB BUT i still see LIKE, i mean, when i liked, i should not see like again, right ?

Comment: What does `$all` return after you like the page? Also, you might want to post your database structure of the related tables.

Comment: $all returns all affected rows (activity table)

Comment: the problem now is, when i click on like, i need to refresh the page to see unlike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference to `$(this)` in `$.post` is incorrect. You probably assumed `$(this)` will be the `.like` element, but that's not the case. `this` in a `$.post` would return something similar:

```
Object { readyState=1, getResponseHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}
Object { url="callback.php", type="POST", isLocal=false, more...}
```

The code below should change the text accordingly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.like', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var likes_count = $('.likes_count');
        if($(this).attr('title')=='Like'){
            $.post('callback.php',{k:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'},function(){
                $this.text('Unlike');
                $this.attr('title','Unlike');
                var likes = parseInt(likes_count.text())+1;
                likes_count.text(likes);
            });
        }else{
            if($(this).attr('title')=='Unlike'){
                $.post('callback.php',{k:$(this).attr('id'),action:'unlike'},function(){
                    $this.text('Like');
                    $this.attr('title','Like');
                    var likes = parseInt(likes_count.text())-1;
                    likes_count.text(likes);
                });
             }
         }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Unlike & Like (they are for the title, not for callback) as you see ($.post('callback.php',{k:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'},function(){) a lower case...

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Check if the updated answer works for you.

Comment: Cool, but the affected rows ($all) still the same, when i click on LIKE 23, i see UNLIKE 23, should be UNLIKE 24 right ? echo '<a href="#" class="like" id="'.$k.'" title="Like">Like</a> <b>'.$all.'</b>'; Is there a way to echo $all+1

Comment: @Simdine I've updated my answer. This should work, but have in mind you might need to make some changes to get it to work if you have multiple pages to like and multiple like counters for every page. By the way, when you ask a question here on SO, please tell what your code should be doing in the question so that people would be able to better understand what you want to do. :)